# How to calculate duration in days?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, pdo

I have to make a notification after 30 days.

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$date = date_create($row['data']);
$laikotarpas = date_diff(new DateTime("now"), $date);
// var_dump($liko);
$liko = 30 - $laikotarpas->d;
```

I want correct result in days.
I have added a row at 2014.03.19 and this shows that left 3days to 30.

My goal is to achieve:
I add record at 2014.03.19 and get result how many days have passed from today. I thought that $laikotarpas->d gives a duration in days, but, when i do calculations to set the limit for 30days.
So my main problem is to get correct $liko, but I have no idea how.
I am adding my time using this code (using PDO):

```
$q->execute(array($name, 
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())
);
```

In my database I use DATETIME. And i print that date from SQL using this php:

```
<?php echo date_format(date_create($data['data']), 'Y-m-d'); ?>
```

Is my way good? How to improve this?

-----edit-----

I have to use php5.2

Just got an idea, it takes only days and ignores months passed count. How to update that to count duration only in days?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the difference between now and a date in the past, try something like this:

## PHP >= 5.2.0

```
$then = '2014-03-19';
$date = new DateTime($then);
$now = new DateTime('now');
$diff = $date->diff($now);

echo $diff->days . ' days since ' . $then . PHP_EOL; // 58 days since 2014-03-19
```

## PHP < 5.2.0

```
$date = strtotime($then);
$now = time();
$diff = $now - $date;
$days = round($diff / 60 / 60 / 24); // convert seconds to days and round off
```

---

**Note:** after understanding more about your problem, I highly suggest you filter your results based on date ranges in MySQL rather than PHP - it'll be easier and more economic and will reduce your potential risk for affecting data you didn't mean to. [See Cull Larson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23691369/2812842).

Comment: But how to do calculations with days to limit them. For example i want to notify my customer 5days before 30days (send e-mail after 25 days passed)passed from the time the record was added to database.

Comment: By the way i am using php 5.2

Comment: @pvaitonis you should be selecting the customers to contact 5 days before 30 days out in your MySQL query, not doing it in PHP. Minimise your potential for mistakes to happen by only selecting the appropriate customers to send to in MySQL then do the sending in PHP (verify the date again in PHP if you want to).

Comment: P.s. the DateTime class was introduced in PHP 5.2.0 so you're fine

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATE(signupDate) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY);
```

That will give you all results with a signup date that is 25 days old.  If you have a flag in the table telling you whether you've notified them, you can pass that along too:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE notified=false AND DATE(signupDate) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY);
```

If you want to get every record 25 days or older, that hasn't been notified:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE notified=false AND DATE(signupDate) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY);
```